# flask: convert utc time to user's local time

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc, pytz

I'm trying to convert a UTC time to the appropriate local time in a flask application. I'm wondering if I can **detect** the user's timezone and dynamically set it.

This is my code so far which works for everyone in the `US/Pacific` timezone only (`datetimefilter` pulled from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803906/utc-to-local-timezone-in-a-flask-jinja-template))

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
import datetime
import pytz

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.template_filter('datetimefilter')
def datetimefilter(value, format='%b %d %I:%M %p'):
    tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')  # timezone you want to convert to from UTC (America/Los_Angeles)
    utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
    value = utc.localize(value, is_dst=None).astimezone(pytz.utc)
    local_dt = value.astimezone(tz)
    return local_dt.strftime(format)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    return render_template_string(
        '''
        <h4>UTC --> Local Time</h4>
        Datetime right now is:
        <p>{{ dt | datetimefilter }} (utc --> local)</p>
        ''',
        dt=dt, now=now)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I imagine this can't be handled server-side because the timezone will always be set to wherever the server is located? Is there a way to handle this by changing `datetimefilter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to dynamically detect user's local time on a website, it's easiest to get browser's datetime via JavaScript [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) object. This way, you can display the correct local time without having to detect anything in the literal sense. Your snippet might look like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    return render_template_string(
        '''
        <html><body>
        <h4>UTC --> Local Time</h4>
        Datetime right now is:
        <p>{{ dt | datetimefilter }} (utc)</p>
        <p><span id="timeNow"></span> (local)</p>
        <script>
        var elem = document.getElementById("timeNow")
        var now = new Date();
        var options = { month: 'short', day: '2-digit',
                        hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit' };
        elem.innerHTML = now.toLocaleString('en-us', options);
        </script>
        </body></html>
        ''',
        dt=dt)
```

And it will render following result, depending on the user's local time:

```
UTC --> Local Time
Datetime right now is:

Dec 02 06:20 PM (utc)

Dec 03, 4:20 PM (local)
```

Then, if you need to save or process some data depending on the user's local time, you can add another **@app.route** ([with POST-method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40623803/3576508)) to receive that Date() value [via AJAX](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api) from the website's front-end.

Upon receiving on the back-end side, you probably want [to parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8155702/3576508) javascript Date() object (note, that in this case it's better to use plain `getTime()` method, instead of `toLocaleString()` formatting) into Python's `datetime`, validate it via e.g. [webargs](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html)/marshmallow, and keep it in, say, user's [session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions).

Please note that similar question has already [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12145847/3576508) earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively compact solution using modern browser APIs.  It uses Javascript to get the browser's timezone, sends it to the back-end to be stored in the session object, and uses the stored timezone in a Jinja filter that can be applied to any UTC datetime to shift it to the user's timezone.

```py
import pytz

from flask import request, session


@app.route('/set_timezone', methods=['POST'])
def set_timezone():
    '''Get timezone from the browser and store it in the session object.'''
    timezone = request.data.decode('utf-8')
    session['timezone'] = timezone
    return ""

@app.template_filter('localtime')
def localtime_filter(value):
    '''Use timezone from the session object, if available, to localize datetimes from UTC.'''
    if 'timezone' not in session:
        return value

    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/34832184
    utc_dt = pytz.utc.localize(value)
    local_tz = pytz.timezone(session['timezone'])
    local_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(local_tz)
    return local_dt
```

And in the `<head>` element of your base template, add this to have the browser send its timezone to the `/set_timezone` route on the first pageload:

```html
{% if 'timezone' not in session %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Send browser's timezone to server for displaying dates/times in local timezone.
  const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  fetch("/set_timezone", {method: 'POST', body: timezone});
</script> 
{% endif %}
```