# Parsing date string form javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python, date, datetime

I have a javascript date object, which i turn into a string, and send to my backend to parse using python.

here is an example of the javascript date string `'Mon Aug 18 2014 21:11:54 GMT+0200 (Centraleuropæisk sommertid)`

I have made a python helper function to help parse the date.

```
def datetime_converter(datetime_str):
    return datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

this should correctly parse the date according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153631/js-date-object-to-python-datetime)

i think the problem is that there is an extra text attached to the end (It's danish since I'm from Denmark)
`(Centraleuropæisk sommertid)`

does anybody know a workaround for this?
i could split the string for a `(` but that does not seem like a good solution.

Here is the exception i get `data 'Mon Aug 18 2014 21:11:54 GMT+0200 (Centraleuropæisk sommertid)' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'`

Comment: You might also be interested in this other [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284850/datetime-strptime-set-format-to-ignore-trailing-part-of-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your case:

```
from email import utils
utils.parsedate_to_datetime('Mon Aug 18 2014 21:11:54 GMT+0200 (Centraleuropæisk sommertid)')
```

You can convert in the format you want hereon.

Comment: What does this return?

Comment: returns `datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 18, 21, 11, 54)`

Comment: Though this doesn't honor the timezone. If you remove GMT from the string, it will.

Comment: @SebastinSanty the problem is that removing the GMT part would be quite a hassle, because the language/format can be different for each language. So splitting it would cause some problems.

Answer (score -1):

So I would suggest using the javascript Date `.toISOString()` method ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)) instead, which gives you an [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)-formatted date-string (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`), and then you could simply change the parser function accordingly:

```py
def datetime_converter(datetime_str: str) -> datetime:
    return datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Since python 3.6, you are also able type-annotate your python code, following the [PEP-528](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) standard

Comment: Very interesting, What is that syntax you are using for the function?

Comment: [Python type annotation](https://dev.to/dstarner/using-pythons-type-annotations-4cfe), which, if you are working on larger projects, or just want to read code you wrote 3 months ago, can be quite helpful in finding out how a function is supposed to be used.

Comment: Very nice trick actually, I was not aware you could do this. I have only tried something similar using the dataclass API from python.

Comment: It can be quite helpful indeed, especially if paired with [docstrings](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/docstrings-python), and more sensible function name, like `parse_ISO8601`, and a docstring like:
   '''Parses an ISO8601 date into a python datetime object
    
    Arguments:
    date_string (str): An ISO8601 formatted datetime string

    Returns:
    datetime:A datetime-object representing the time of the input-string

    '''
However in this case that is unnecessary

Comment: @baileyhaldwin did you remember to change the format of the string sent from your frontend?